# Issue calling a function

Tags: python, function, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called `ro` which has all claims for automotive parts, What I want now is to create a function called `part_dataframe` where I can subset the original `ro`into a new dataframe with only a particular part, let say compressor with the subset name as `comp_claims`

My function is:

```
def part_dataframe(first_frame, subset, type_number, number):
   subset = first_frame.loc[first_frame[type_number] == number]
   subset = subset.reset_index(drop=True)
   subset['word'] = subset.Comment.str.split().apply(lambda x: pd.value_counts(x).to_dict())
```

When I tried to call the function:

```
part_dataframe(ro, comp_claims, 'Part No.', '97701')
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-65cf8428af26> in <module>()
----> 1 part_dataframe(ro, comp_claims, 'Part No.', '97701')

NameError: name 'comp_claims' is not defined
```

How can I fix that?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you sure you assigned a value to `comp_claims` before calling the `part_dataframe` function? Check spellings and scopes.

Comment: Why does the function immediately overwrite `subset`, the `comp_claims` you want to pass in? Should it be the return value?

Comment: Can you show the full code, including where you define `comp_claims`?

Comment: yes, you're right, `comp_claims`is only the name of my new subset that i want to create which will filter the column `Part No.` from the dataframe `ro` by the number `97701`, `comp_claims` will be a new dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ro = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Part No.': np.arange(10)}
)

def part_dataframe(first_frame, type_number, number):
    return first_frame.loc[first_frame[type_number] == number]

subset = part_dataframe(ro, 'Part No.', 3)
subset
```

[image]